# defference between hide comments and output comments

Tags: jsp

I'm preparing for an interview so while reading some questions I found that the "JSP comment is called hide comment whereas html comment is called output comment". And the answer says that if we try to view source in JSP, the comments will not be shown whereas in HTML, it will be shown.

But I'm able to see the comment in the view source section. Can anybody clear this doubt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSP comment is called hide comment whereas html comment is called output comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184065/jsp-comment-is-called-hide-comment-whereas-html-comment-is-called-output-comment)

Answer (score 0):

Jsp files gets compiled before they are ready to sent over the network. So, if you put any comment in Java code, compiler do not care about it and simply trims it in compiled version of code.hurrah, what happened? The comment is no more view-able because it was ignored and removed by the compiler.

Now in case of HTML, the HTML files do not pass through any compilation phase. They are directly rendered by the browser. Now here, browser doesn't trim them, but simply ignores their existence while rendering.

As a result, comments in JSP file are deleted/trimmed/removed (or whatever you want to say) and HTML comments are only ignored. So they are view-able.

This is why jsp comments are called hide comments and html comments are called output comment.

Now coming to your last line..

Where is the code? Put the code which causes you trouble. Anyone capable from the community will  definitely solve your doubts.

And all the best for interview..!! Good Luck. :)